# Difference between child and isolated scopes in directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I was trying to understand scopes in AngularJS directives. From what I gather there are three types:

1. scope inherited from parent controller
2. child scope (`scope: true`)
3. isolated scope (`scope: {}`)

I understand the first one. The second one, 'child scope' is defined as:

> scope prototypically inherited from the parent controller

and 'isolated scope' is defined as

> scope specific to the directive and not inherited from the
>   parent controller

In layman terms, what exactly is the difference between 'child scope' and 'isolated scope'? **What are their respective use cases?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With respect to the type of scope to use, here are some of the guiding principles i follow. This knowledge also stem looking an number of Angular and third party directives

Use the parent scope if you just need to add some behaviour to existing DOM elements, `ng-click`, `ng-show`, `ng-class` are good examples of it. These directives do not come with their own template UI but just extend behaviour of exiting html elements.

Use `scope:true`, or a child scope when your directive plans to add new properties on the scope and do not want to pollute the parent scope with such properties. Very few Angular directive do it, `ng-repeat` creates a child scope for each iterated element and exposes some properties on the child scope like `$index`. I would suggest when creating directives at least create this.

Isolated scope created using `scope:{}` are used by true components where input to the directive is explicit through scope property and is not affect by parent scope directly. This helps us create a truely self contained reusable directive. There are some challenges with isolated directive such as two isolated directives cannot be applied on same html element, that you need to be aware of.

Regarding the nuances of scope inheritance, you have to read https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes there is no way out.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to look at isolated scope would probably be to look at 2 instances of the same directive

```
<div ng-controller="someController">
    <my-directive>
      <input ng-model ="user.name">
      {{ user.name}}
    </my-directive>
    <my-directive>
      <input ng-model ="user.name">
      {{ user.name}}
    </my-directive>
</div>
```

Without isolated scope `user.name` would be in the parent  scope. Changing the input in either instance would therefore change it in the other instance as well , since they both reference the same variable

When scope is isolated, each instance would have it's own value for `user.name` and changes in one instance won't affect the other instance

Comment: Ok so isolated scope is used when we do not want to use the scope of the controller. But what about child scope? When is it used and what is meant by 'prototypically inherits'?

Comment: suggest you google the inheritance term . It is a fundamental javascript object concept

Comment: This will definitely help you https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: looks complicated ;) Are there any explanations on when to use which scope?

Comment: @TarunDugar not really because directives are very powerful and can be used to do lots of different things

Answer (score 1):

When scope is set to "true", AngularJS will create a new scope by inheriting parent scope.

When scope is set to "false" (or nothing is set), the controller and directive are using the same scope object.

When scope: {}, directive gets a new isolated scope.

Details can be found [here](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/).